# View other conference call participants on SIP?

Tags: sip, voip, rtp

This is my scenario:

1. I dial into a VoIP call using SIP (e.g., 11234567890@10.0.100.200)
2. As the first caller, I get placed on hold
3. Another user dials into that same conference
4. The conference call starts

Does SIP or RTP provide for a way for me to view the other participants (their name or number) on the call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if your UAC and your conference provider supports [RFC 4575](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4575): A Session Initiation Protocol (SIP) Event Package for Conference State

In that case you would be able to establish a subscription (SUBSCRIBE) with the `conference` event package and (subject to appropriate permissions, authorizations, etc. at the discretion of the conference provider) you will get NOTIFYed about conference events. What events to notify is at the discretion of the conference provider (note the language in the RFC, no MUSTs, some SHOULDs and MAYs):

```
3.6.  Notifier Generation of NOTIFY Requests

   Notifications SHOULD be generated for the conference state when a new
   participant joins (i.e., gets "connected" to) or a participant leaves
   (i.e., gets "disconnected" from) the conference.

   Subject to a local focus policy, additional changes in participants'
   status, changes in their media types, and other optional information
   MAY be reported by the focus.

   Changes in sidebar rosters SHOULD be reported by the focus to their
   participants and MAY be reported to others, subject to local policy.

   Changes in conference identifiers and service URIs SHOULD be reported
   by the focus to the conference package subscribers.

   Changes in other conference state information MAY be reported by the
   focus to the conference package subscribers.
```

You can probably expect it from IMS CONF service according to [3GPP TS 24.605](http://www.3gpp.org/DynaReport/24605.htm) and [3GPP TS 24.147](http://www.3gpp.org/DynaReport/24147.htm)

Comment: My conference provider only mentions "Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, NOTIFY, MESSAGE" in the SIP invitation response, does that mean it doesn't support NOTIFY? Is there any other way I can view the other participants?

Comment: @Steven, that's an RFC-backed way that I know about. There might be other ways, proprietary or using different technologies (e.g. I could think of a REST service that could allow you to query the conference). Even though SUSBSCRIBE is not in the Allow list, I'd still try it (if you have that capability). The impression I get from RFC 3261 is that Allow in INVITE and INVITE responses indicate methods that can be used within the dialog. You can use OPTIONS to poll more general capabilities... Even if SUBSCRIBE is supported, the conference event package needs to be supported too.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [RestComm](https://github.com/Mobicents/RestComm) to simplify this, it provides a demo on conferencing out of the box. (Dial 3010 or 3011). RestComm use SIP and RTP for the initial conference setup but then you can query the conference via REST for managing participants (mute/unmute, add/remove from conference, ...)